# n is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
if n in range(6, 21) or n % 2 != 0:
    print("Weird")
else:
    print("Not Weird")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
```

The following code is supposed to print "weird" output for odd numbers and "Not weird" for even numbers but instead it is crashing.

Comment: Because the interpreter starts with `if` and sees `n` not defined before...

Comment: `if __name__ == '__main__':` is a regular `if` statement, not magic syntax. The code runs from top to bottom.

Comment: But isnt n defined as an input. Down below, it should take user's input and store it as n

Comment: @AlexHall so what should I do ? Because the code template was given with that if statement

Comment: `n = int(input())` must be at the top of the file

Comment: @user7959693, that comes later, Python is generally as an interpreted language, and here also its the same. Meaning it will read from line 1, and go forward one by one. At line 1, the interpreter does not even know that you have an input read later.

Comment: I think the confusion here is that you’re expecting variables to work something like spreadsheet cells, but that doesn’t work in imperative code like yours. That `If n in ...` is referring to whatever value `n` names right now, as that line is executing. Since you don’t give it a value until later, it doesn’t have a value right now, so you get an error.

Comment: @user7959693 to use the `if` template, read `n` before the `if`..

Comment: Forget the `if __name__ == '__main__':` unless you know what it's for and you know that you need it (you probably don't). Then define `n` at the top before trying to use it.

Comment: Flagging as a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = int(input())

if n in range(6, 21) or n % 2 != 0:
    print("Weird")
else:
    print("Not Weird")
```

`n` does not exist at the point by which are you calling it. The compiler looks line by line.

Comment: Solved. Thank you